# Get target group arn from aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to get the arn of a target group that contains the word test or the value assigned to "value" in its name, but I can't get it, I got this error.

```
value=test
```

```
aws elbv2 describe-target-groups --query "TargetGroups[?starts_with(TargetGroupName, '${value}') == `true`].[TargetGroupArn]"
```

```
Bad value for --query TargetGroups[?starts_with(TargetGroupName, 'test') == ].[TargetGroupArn]: invalid token: Parse error at column 59, token "]" (RBRACKET), for expression:
"TargetGroups[?starts_with(TargetGroupName, 'test') == ].[TargetGroupArn]"
                                                       ^
```

I am using bash on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've used backticks around your true value:

```
`true`
```

try replacing them with single-quotes instead.

```
'true'
```